# I need to pass stored procedure name dynamically to Linq-to-SQL, vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

How can I pass stored procedure name dynamically to Linq-to-SQL, vb.net and get the result into a datatable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like you're shoe horning with the wrong technology.  If you want a DataTable and you want to use a dynamic proc name, why not just use ADO.NET for this query.  No reason you have to force this to be a Linq-to-SQL thing.

Answer (score 4):

LINQ to SQL is all about compile-time type-safety and avoiding DataTables.

You should use classic ADO.Net, using a `SqlDataAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

you can either use `ExecuteQuery<T>(string Your Query)`.First build your string and then execute it and return T result and then iterate it to DataTable.